# animate 300 divs performance issue

Tags: css, 3d, css-transitions, css-transforms

Couple months ago I write a pen like bokeh bubbles that create perspective tunnel.
It runs fast in actual Crome and Opera.

here is pen on codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGrbPJ

And seems like the animation jitters too much in IE11 and FireFox 46.

I thought that there should be some workaround to increase draw speed like:

```
  backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Or applying 3d hardware acceleration, like add:

```
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

But this doesn't give much boost.

Maybe someone is expert in 3d transitions in css who know what causing such jittering in IE and FF, and can point me to where to look at?

Sincerely!

Vitaly.

Comment: Your codepen is a pain to work with... Could you inset your code in a snippet?

Comment: why? there 60 string of sass code, I can make it on jsfiddle but the problem is visible from codepen if run it in firefox. What causing pain?